# Clone GitLab Project with Azure AD V2 authentication in eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, gitlab, azure-ad-v2

I am using azure ad v2 to login my gitlab account and i wanted to clone project in eclipse. But when trying to clone the project it requires user name and password. Since i am using azure ad v2 i don't have user name and password to prompt.

[image]

how can i pass the authentication to clone the project.

Thanks

---

Answer (score 0):

Go to user settings -> password and create new password. That password can be use to authenticate.